# Publisher which subscribes to its own topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm currently designing an application which is will have hundreds of log-compacted topics. Each topic is related to a failover group and should have a dynamic (e.g., to be changed on demand) set of producers and consumers.

For example, let's say I have 3 failover instances related to topic T1. Each of those failover instances should have the same data / state (eventually consistent). And each of the instances may consume and produce messages on that topic.

As I understand, I need to assign different group IDs for each consumer/producer in order to have every instance read the topic entirely.

Though given that the number of readers and writers for a topic are not fixed, how is it possible to avoid reading ones own messages for that topic?

Sure, I could add a source ID to the message and just dismiss the message when the consumer figures out that he is about to read a message he previously produced himself. But I'd rather avoid the data transfer entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Producers and consumers are independent processes. If you subscribe to the same topic that's being produced to without some extra processing logic, you'll end up with an infinite loop.

You also cannot have more consumers than partitions, so the dynamic consumer amount will be limited by that.

> need to assign different group IDs for each consumer/producer in order to have every instance read the topic entirely

Not necessarily. You've mentioned you have compacted topics, so I assume you are using Kafka Streams. In the Streams API, you can set `num.standby.replicas` for copying statestore data across instances of the same `application.id`

Comment: I thought when consumers are in different groups, they can read from the same partition? And thus in that configuration there can be n consumers for a single partition?

Comment: This is true, but then they'd all be reading different offsets, as well, and not have consistent information between all instances